# sed -- need to enter the text after nth line of text match

Tags: sed

i'm using below code in a script and it's should match "title AHS - zarriot CBTS random Linux Servers" in hosts.test and insert text of t3 file into hosts.test after 2 lines of match strings. But it's throwing some error.

```
sed -i.bak '/^title AHS - zarriot CBTS random Linux Servers$/ {N;N; r t3}' hosts.test
```

Could anyone assist me in this?

Comment: Varun, welcome to stack overflow. Please show us sample input in code tags and expected output in code tags.

Comment: see also https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Commands-Requiring-a-newline

Comment: thanks for replying..thums up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i.bak '/^title AHS - zarriot CBTS random Linux Servers$/!b;N;N;r t3' file
```

The `r t3` command needs to be terminated with a newline. Alternative:

```
sed -i.bak -e '/^title AHS - zarriot CBTS random Linux Servers$/{N;N;r t3' -e '}' file
```

Splits the commands up into two using the `-e` option. Or using Bash:

```
sed -i.bak $'/^title AHS - zarriot CBTS random Linux Servers$/{N;N;r t3\n}' file
```